# GCP: Stripe webhook error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, stripe-payments

Stripe version: "8.107.0"

I keep getting a Stripe webhook verification error whenever I run my webhook on GCP. I've tried using the raw body in the signature, as the code snippet below mentions, as well as other ways to pass the req.rawBody as other StackOverflow answers mention.

The weird thing is that this error seems to be thrown when I deploy to GCP, and not when I run locally. I tried to manually create the signature (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-manually), and the same result there: locally the signatures match, on GCP it doesn't.

Our server is hosted on GCP GKE, and we serve requests to our server through an Nginx Reverse Proxy. Other stack overflow solutions mentioned Google Cloud Functions and Lambda. As far as I'm aware, we do not parse requests on GCP

**I do use bodyParser.json(), but that's setup after this endpoint.** These are the ways I've tried creating / using a rawBody:

```js
app.use(express.json({verify: (req,res,buf) => { req.rawBody = buf }}));
```

```js
bodyParser.json({
     verify: (req: any, res, buf) => {
      req.rawBody = buf.toString();
    },
  }),
```

```js
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, webhookSecret);
```

I based my code on the stripe example found here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/node-express/express.js

```js
// Stripe requires the raw body to construct the event
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, webhookSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    // On error, log and return the error message
    console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Successfully constructed event
  console.log('✅ Success:', event.id);

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({received: true});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with one of our setup files, where basically a space or an \n character was getting added to our webhookSecret

Comment: Interesting! Happy to hear you figured it out. It's critical that the raw body not be modified so this makes sense. Any idea how/why it was happening like that?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem here, and it was fixed by looking for a development webhook secret (as we have a different url for development environment - it is a different webhook secret - consider look that when you have this problem).